# Jump cut editing in the Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to edit a long video, deleting parts of it. I think this type of editing is called ***jump cut***. What would be an efficient way to do it in Blender? Just soft/hard cutting the video and sound strips on two different frames, deleting the middle strip and moving together the remaining parts? Or is there a better way?

I found an add-on called "[Jump to Cut](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Jump_to_cut)", but I'm not sure if I understand how it works and if it could be useful for this purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC I think that was just a UI addon to skip to the next edit point after you've added cuts.

Answer (score 1):

The *Jump to Cut* Addon assembles various important tools, which can be found in the Blender Sequencer, but has no premade method to create jump cuts.

The manual way is already rather fast.

1. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the movie strip.
2. Position the cursor at the beginning of the jump cut.
3. Soft Cut with <kbd>K</kbd>.
4. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>Select the start handle of the 2nd part of the 
   strip.
5. Move it forward a  number of frames. Assuming you want to jump forwards a second in 24 fps the shortcuts would be <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.
6. Remove the gap. <kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd> or *Strip > Remove Gaps*.

[image]

Comment: You could also just add cuts to a strip the Slide the contents of each one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking this question because manually editing with jump cuts takes too much time, there is software to automate it. TimeBolt is a desktop software for Mac/PC to remove dead air and silence with jump cuts.

The software is helpful for creators who want to release shows on a consistent schedule and want to save time editing video or audio.

[See TimeBolt](https://www.timebolt.io)

Comment: Not sure 3rd party software fits the _"What would be an efficient way to do it in Blender?"_ part of the question.

Comment: I posted a solution to a problem Blender (nor any other software) currently solves. And yes, TimeBolt is my software.